# FXML: is it possible to access the namespace of the loader of an fx:include?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am working on th GUI of an JavaFX application which shall show/hide some GUI elements due to identification of the logged user.
I would like to prepare this by defining properties programmatically which are written to the namespace of the fxml loader. This works fine, but unfortunately not on the fxml in the fx:include tags.
Is it possible to access the namespace of the loaders of the included fxml (if so: how?), or should I renounce the use of fx:include here?
Any recommendation is highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

in Java:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("some_key1", "some_value1"); 
prop.setProperty("some_key2", "some_value2"); 
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/path/to/fxml.fxml"));
            prop.stringPropertyNames()
                    .forEach(key -> loader.getNamespace().put(key, prop.getProperty(key)));
```

in the parent FXML:

```
<Label fx:id="label" maxHeight="20.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="30.0" text="${some_key1}"/> /* here some_value1 appears */
<TabPane id="tabPane" fx:id="tabPane" minHeight="860.0" tabMaxHeight="30.0" tabMaxWidth="200.0" tabMinHeight="30.0" tabMinWidth="100.0">
      <Tab id="tab" fx:id="Tab" closable="false" disable="true" text="Text">
             <fx:include fx:id="tabContent" source="tab-content.fxml" />
       </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

In the child FXML:

```
<Label fx:id="label" maxHeight="20.0" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="30.0" text="${some_key2}"/> /* here some_value2 does not appear */
```

Comment: I think you have to this via controllers - I don’t know of a way to do it via the namespace

Comment: Thank you very much, James_D. I removed injection and created a custom Tab Class which includes its fxml.